# Stata - Cohort Study - Display Crude Risk Ratio (like r(rr_crude))

Tags: stata

I'm starting to use Stata 14. I'm trying to do some basic risk ratio analysis, but I don't know how to extract single results. Given the following code:

```
clear all
webuse ugdp
cs case exposed [fw=pop], by(age)
```

we get an output with four risk ratios, for both age categories, a crude one and a M-H one. With

```
dis r(rr)
```

I get the last (?) ratio, but is it possible to specify it? Like

```
dis r(rr_crude)
dis r(rr_mh)
```

or something like that? I haven't found a solution. Or is it possible to do something like saving the output in a matrix and indicating it with row and column indices?
I haven't found a solution in the documentation.

Comment: Please note site policy on keeping personal comment in posts to a minimum.  That's why your post was trimmed down. We are happy to believe that you are polite and will be grateful. See e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: `return list` shows what is available. It doesn't include all that you want. Not my field, so I can't comment on why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
Just create scalars, which persist in memory

```
 clear all
 webuse ugdp
 cs case exposed [fw=pop], by(age)
 scalar rr_mh = r(rr)
```

Then use `glm`:

```
 glm case exposed [fw = pop], family(binomial) link(log)
 scalar rr_crude = exp(_b[exposed])
```

or

```
 cs case exposed [fw = pop]
 scalar rr_crude = r(rr)
```

In either case:

```
 di rr_crude 
 di rr_mh
```

Comment: but then you loose the rr_mh. i could do `cs case exposed [fw=pop]` `dis r(rr)` which is the crude one and then do it with the strata to get the rr_mh with `r(rr)`. but i want to do it both at the same time.

Comment: Just create a new scalar rr_mh.  I've modified the answer to show  this.

Comment: @dan If you accept Steve's answer you will gain reputation (as will Steve).

Comment: actually, the idea is to do it with one call, not to double the calculation time by using the procedure twice. both risk ratios are provided in one output, so it has to be possible to extract its results - my opinion.

Comment: All the scalars  returned after `cs` are shown by `return list` . If you run it after `cs`, you will see that only one risk ratio is returned, contained in `r(rr)`.  So, while, like you, I would expect the command to return both ratios, StataCorp obviously thought otherwise.  You can test the extra time needed to run `cs` twice  by using `timer`.